# Running `manage.py` for `makemessages` from another directory

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Is there a way to use manage.py from another directory to create makemessages for an installed_app?

```
├── common
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── tracking
│   │   │   ├── locale
├── car
│   ├── interfaces
│   │   ├── control
│   │   │   ├── manage.py
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your scenario? Where is the installed app located, and where are you trying to run `manage.py` from?

Comment: I need to run makemessages from car/interfaces/control/manage.py in common/common/tracking/locale

Comment: Are you sure? `makemessages` is supposed to be run from the directory you want to _search for messages_, but the `locale` directory only holds the _already collected_ message catalogs, `makemessages` likely won't find anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it from directory bellow like this:

```
python ../manage.py makemessages
```

if it is two directories bellow:

```
python ../../manage.py makemessages
```